# How to stop SignalR from queueing alerts

Tags: javascript, .net, signalr

I have a .NET application that sends a javascript alert to the users when another user adds something new. However, if 12 other users each add something there are 12 alerts back to back. I only need one, the first one. Is there a way to clear all the alerts when the first is clicked? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe just don’t raise new alerts on the client side but check if you should actually raise a new one.

Comment: @poke How would you check to see if the user has clicked the alert yet. Also keep in mind there are thousands of users.

Comment: Couldn't this be done Client side where you are raising the alert? If an alert is visible currently, dont show it again, same with click on an alert, set a flag or something saying display them or not.

Comment: @Tyriddik I would do it on only the client side. The server sends a notification to the client, and the client then determines how to visualize that. If there’s already an alert active, then just skip a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out a way our this by doing the following.

```
var alertHub = $.connection.EventHub;
var alertVisable = false;

// Set the Alert method
alertHub.client.Alert = function () {
    if (alertVisable === false) {
        alertVisable = true;
        //alert("New Data Available!");
        if (confirm("Additional comments are now available, would you like to load them?")) {
            refreshPage();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                alertVisable = false;
            }, 300000)
        }
    }
}
$.connection.hub.start().done();
```

I set a variable to false on load and change it to true when the alert is called. No more alerts will run till the variable is set to true again. In my case I told cancel button to not set the variable back to false for 5 minutes. I hope this can help others.